# How to install Dart SDK on Fedora 29?

Tags: linux, fedora, sdk, dart

The Bash Commands in Dart Documentation to install it's sdk is for Ubuntu (using apt-get).
I used `dnf install dart` but it returned the followig error:

```
 No match for argument: dart
    Error: Unable to find a match
```

I'm using Fedora 29.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building-Dart-on-CentOS,-Red-Hat,-Fedora-and-Amazon-Linux-AMI

Comment: Thanks, I did everything as instructed but how to get started with Dart? When I enter dart in terminal it reutrns an error that such command doesn't exiests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No need to build from source:-

You can Use this archive to download specific versions of the Dart SDK and the Dart API documentation. [Dart SDK Archive](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is 10 months old, but this worked for me. As for RPM-based distributions, according to my understanding, Dart is not available for installation through a software repository, so you need to build it from the source.

As somebody has suggested above, if you consult the [official documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building-Dart-on-CentOS,-Red-Hat,-Fedora-and-Amazon-Linux-AMI), you're on the right tracks. Pay attention that you might want to install Python 2 on your system if you're running later versions of Fedora which dropped support for it.

```
$ sudo dnf install python2 -y
```

Next, just go top to bottom instruction-wise

```
$ sudo dnf install git subversion make gcc-c++ -y
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
$ export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/depot_tools
$ mkdir dart-sdk && cd dart-sdk && fetch dart
```

This operation might take some time. Lastly, build the 64-bit SDK

```
$ cd dart-sdk/sdk && ./tools/build.py --mode release --arch x64 create_sdk
```

Upon completion, the SDK should be available in `out/ReleaseX64/dart-sdk` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
$ ./tools/build.py --no-goma --mode release --arch x64 create_sdk
```

Instead of:

```
$ ./tools/build.py --mode release --arch x64 create_sdk
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).